# What is the meaning of max() in intro. to algorithms?

Tags: time-complexity, terminology, notation

I'm reading chapter 3(growth functions) of CLRS and in giving an example of proving theta for a standard quadratic function the book gives the following value for $n_0 = 2 \cdot max(|b|/a, \sqrt{|c|/a})$ .

I'm confused regarding what **"max"** means in this context. The quadratic function is $an^2 + bn + c$ and the constants give are $c_1 = a/4, c_2 =7a/4$.

I'm thinking it might mean which ever of the parameters yields a larger value?

Comment: Yes, it refers to the maximum of those two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as confirmed by Gokul, $\max(p,q)$ just means the larger one of its two parameters, $p$ and $q$. It can also apply to more parameters such as $\max(p, q, r, s, t)$, where it means the largest of all 5 variables or values.

Its opposite is $\min$, which is used in the same way but means the smaller one of two values or the smallest one of all given values.

You might want to check [the list of mathematical abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations) the next time you get confused by some math abbreviations.